# Solr - LukeRequestHandler - Need Indexing status

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, luke

I am trying to display the status of Solr Index to an admin in my application. This snippet would contain:

- Index Last Update Date
- Index Current Status (Idle | Indexing | Error)
- Button to Trigger Indexing on-demand

Note: I am using DataImportHandler to refresh my index.

I am using the Luke request handler to get the last updated time of the index:
http://server.dev/solr/core/admin/luke?numTerms=0&fl=0

I could use the dataimporthandler's "status" command to get the Indexing status.

I was wondering if there's a way to get these parameters in a single request?

Answer (score 0):

if can also look at stats (http:// the-host :8983/solr/admin/stats.jsp) that contains lots of info (including the one you want I think)

Comment: am not sure I understand - which endpoint are you referring to?

Comment: stats.jsp is way too verbose - the reason I added the two query params in my luke url is to reduce the verbosity. Stats.jsp bloats up as cores increase.